# On MacOS Catalina ssh -C user@machine echo $path returns blank with zsh

Tags: macos, ssh

How do I set the path variable for remote ssh zsh on MacOS?

I have tried .ssh/environment with:
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin

I've also tried ~/.zsh and ~/.zprofile